# Does anyone use surefire POJO tests?

Tags: java, maven, surefire

Does anyone actually use maven's POJO test feature instead of JUnit/TestNG?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/pojo-test.html

If so what for / why?

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because they're fast, light, and have no dependencies outside of the plugin.

Do I bother? Almost never on any projects of real size.

It's a cheap feature to implement, and allows standalone plugin use. Perhaps it was a testbed for some of their initial functionality before adding the complexity of wrapping up other test frameworks.